# Large volume of data - few actions for data combinations - what data structure?

Tags: data-structures

I am trying to figure out the best data structure to implement for this problem. I have an index file (~ 200000 records) containing Account no.,  Unique ID,  Date, a pdf form name, Taxcode. Based on these values read from the file, I have to assign a few actions (exempt, remove, tax, etc.). Once the action is assigned, I can call the necessary method that implements this action.
The huge volume of data is the reason why I am not able to decide. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide more information?  Is the hard part storing everything, or is it categorizing things?  What have you thought about trying?

Answer (score 0):

200,000 records is not at all a huge volume of data.

Unless each record has to reference another record, you can stream the file.  Read a line, convert it to an object, process that object as needed, call the necessary action, and move on to the next line in the file.

You will have almost zero memory footprint from the data using this method.

Alternatively, you can read the file and create one object per line in one thread, place each object on a queue, and use one or more worker threads to take objects off of the queue and process them.  That will make much better use of multi-core CPUs at the cost of some memory, depending on how large your queue gets.  You can of course set a maximum queue size to avoid running out of memory (the file reader thread would pause when the queue is full, until it becomes not full).